# How can I validate configurations that live under the "parameters" root?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, yaml

I'm working on a project in Symfony 2.3.x.

In `MyBundle\Resources\config\services.yml` I have a service defined as:

```
services:
    myservice:
        class : MyServiceClass
        arguments: [%settings%]
```

The `settings` in the service's argument is defined in a `MyBundle\Resources\config\parameters.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    settings:
        setting1: 15
        setting2: true
```

Everything works great, but I want to validate this file. So in the `MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration` file I have this:

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('parameters');

        $rootNode->children()
            ->arrayNode('settings')
                ->isRequired()
                ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->children()
                    ->integerNode('setting1')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->min(1)->end()
                    ->booleanNode('setting2')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->defaultTrue()->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

In my `MyBundle\DependencyInjection\MyExtension` file I have this:

```
class MyExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $processor = new Processor();
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $processedConfiguration = $processor->processConfiguration(
            $configuration,
            $configs
        );

        $configLoader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $configLoader->load('services.yml');
        $configLoader->load('parameters.yml');
    }
}
```

---

Everything works OK but the problem is, if I change in `Configuration` `min(1)` to `min(100)`, the functionality should break and tell me that my parameters are not ok. Yet, it just keeps working no matter what I do.

So the validation is somehow ignored. I feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here (like maybe the root node should be initialized in another way), but I can't figure out what's going on.

The only documentation on this that I could find is on [Symfony's official page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html). But there is no mention in there for configuration files that have `parameters` as root node (which from what I know are treated in a special way).

How can I make my validation code actually validate the configuration file ?

Thank you in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

Another clue that I just found is, if I first load the `parameters.yml` file and only then call `$processor->processConfiguration`, then I get the exception:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: The child node "settings" at path "parameters" must be configured.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is that there's no way to do what I want in today's Symfony framework implementation. Maybe I'll try to implement it myself and make a pull request for it, at which point I will edit this answer and add the required information.

Answer (score 1):

The `parameters` section is part of the container configuration, not of the bundle configuration. So you either check the arguments inside the constructor to see if the parameters were correct or you do not use the parameters section and move them to the bundle configuration.

Since the settings are properbly configuration settings, I recommend you to put them in the configuration class.

The name of the `root` element in your configuration class doesn't do anything. The di alias of your bundle is used (e.g. AcmeDemoBundle -> `acme_demo`). I would suggest to remove the "setting" node from your configuration, since everything in there are settings. So you can now put this in your `config.yml`:

```
acme_demo:
    setting1: 10
    setting2: false
```

After this, the `$processedConfiguration` variable in your bundle extension (which btw should not have "Bundle" in it) now has an array like `array('setting1' => 10, 'setting2' => false)`. You can use that to set the parameter:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    // ...

    $container->setParameter('acme_demo.settings', $processedConfiguration);
}
```

I would also recommend to use more sensible names, "setting1" and "setting2" don't tell much about what the setting is doing.

Comment: Your solution would work, but I need to maintain the config file in `MyBundle\Resources\config` and it has to keep its structure (with the exception of the `parameters` root, that one I can change to whatever I want). If you know any way in which it would work that way, please tell me, I really appreciate it. I've been spending hours on this... without succes.

Comment: @RaduMurzea as said in the first sentence, you need to do the validation in constructor of the `MyService` class

Comment: OK, but in `MyService`s constructor, how would I call the code that does the validation ? Do I call `MyExtension::load` or `Configuration::getConfigTreeBuilder` manually ? That doesn't seem right. How would the actual code look like ? Could you edit your answer and add a snippet of code so that I can actually get an idea about this ? (doesn't have to be perfect or complete, just as a hint) Pretty please :) . Thank you.

Comment: @RaduMurzea Just use simple if statements: `if (!isset($settings['setting1']) || !is_int($settings['setting1']) || $settings['setting1'] < 1) { // ... failure }`